# Increasing the speed of this algorithm

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make this code run faster, and I am having trouble doing so. I can pass most of my test cases, but as the numbers get larger I cant pass them.

```
Input: 92871036442 3363728910382456 output: 1160053175781729
Input: 1 1000000000000000000        output: 264160473575034274
```

These test cases won't pass. What can I do to speed up my algorithm and prevent it from timing out?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isLuckyNumber(unsigned long long n)
{
    bool found6 = false, found8 = false;
    
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int digit = n % 10;
        if (digit == 6)
        {
            found6 = true;
        }
        else if (digit == 8)
        {
            found8 = true;
        }
        
        //removing last digit
        n = n / 10;
    }
    
    if (found6 && found8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //otherwise if any one of them is true, it is a lucky number
    else if (found6 || found8)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    //otherwise not a lucky number
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    //creating needed variables, using unsigned long long as data type as it
    //can store huge values (between 0 and 18446744073709551615)
    unsigned long long L, R, count = 0;
    
    //reading L and R
    cin >> L >> R;
    
    //looping as long as L<=R
    while (L <= R)
    {
        //if L is lucky number, incrementing count
        
        if (isLuckyNumber(L))
        {
            count++;
        }
        
        //incrementing L
        L++;
    }
    
    //displaying count at the end
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question about?

Comment: Is the desired output just the _total number_ of lucky numbers in some range? You almost certainly want to figure out a way to compute that based on pattern recognition rather than manually checking if each individual number in the range is lucky or not.

Comment: Side note: `//reading L and R` followed by `cin >> L >> R;` is a "No <expletive deleted>, Sherlock!" comment. Don't waste your time making comments like this. Save comments for when you need to explain some complexity. And if you give variables, constants, and functions good, descriptive names, you'll find that's almost never. Write code that documents itself and you'll find you finish the job faster because it almost debugs itself.

Comment: @drum A lucky number is a 10-based number, which has at least a "6" or an "8" in its digits. However, if it has "6" and "8" at the same time, then the number is NOT lucky. For example, "16", "38", "666" are lucky numbers, while "234" , "687" are not.

Now we want to know how many lucky numbers (without leading zeroes) are there between L and R, inclusive? This is the problem statement, and input is two integers, output is an integer indicating the amount of lucky numbers between L, R

Comment: @ChrisMM Ok ill try over there, thanks

Comment: I mean, really. `//incrementing L` and then `L++;` I like self-deprecating humour, but this is insulting.

Comment: You should review the [numeric limits of variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), by `#include <limits>`

Comment: Do you need to check every number? E.g how many lucky numbers are there between 0 and 100? Are there the same number between 100 and 200?

Comment: You rarely want to speed up an algorithm that's already written. Usually when you need performance, the best thing to do is throw it out and replace it with a faster algorithm.

Comment: When playing with digits, I recommend reading the number as a `string`.  You can then use `int digit_value = number_as_string[digit_position] - '0';`  You can also do something line `std::string::size_type position = number_as_string.find('6');` or use some of the `find` or `count` functions in `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That would almost certainly be slower

Comment: There probably is an `O(1)` formula for this.  Why explicitly `6` and `8`, and not, say, `5` and `9`?  That right there indicates there is a trick to this.

Comment: So @MooingDuck, division, a.k.a. `x % 10`, is faster than array access and subtraction?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem wants 6 and 8, im assuming we should dynamically compute larger numbers at once

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Modulo is slower than array access, but to build the array you must first do modulo _and also memory allocation_. A<A+B.

Comment: @tylerj What I'm saying that with assuming an unlimited integer, the solution maybe just a mathematical formula.  If so, then the bottleneck is to how to implement an unlimited integer.  I'm not ruling out that it may not be a formula, but a lot of these questions have solutions that do not require loops.  Have you wondered why the question explicitly mentions `6` and `8`, and not any other two digits?

Comment: @MooingDuck you build the array once though and read it thousands of times and as the number starts life as a string entered into the console building the array is just copying a buffer

Comment: The array is already built before the analysis.  One has to either translate from numeric text to number or spend time allocating memory for the string (expanding).  It would be interesting to profile the difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see what youre saying now. This is a really tricky question, getting to 0(n) wasnt bad, but getting constant time is really tricky and im not finding it

Comment: @tylerj -- The O(1) solutions are almost never obvious, unless you have a background in some sort of number theory.

Comment: When hiring, I'll sometimes throw a question like this into the mix, not to see a solution, but to see the process the applicant takes to solve it. If they get it, cool. If they don't, you can learn a lot about someone from how they deal with failure. The Ol' Kobayashi Maru test.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the numbers in range 0 - 10<sup>n</sup>-1, they are the combinations with repetitions of the 10 digits.

The number of combinations without a specified digit is 9<sup>n</sup>, if you want to exclude two digits is 8<sup>n</sup>.

Lucky numbers are defined as the set of combinations containing either 6 or 8 but not both. Using basic set theory we can extract some formulas.

N is the total range with cardinality |N| = 10<sup>n</sup>

N-6, N-8 are the set of number not containing 6 or 8, |N-6| = |N-8| = 9<sup>n</sup>

N-68, numbers containing neither 6 nor 8, |N-68| = 8<sup>n</sup>.

From this we can calculate all cardinalities:

|N+6| = |N| - |N-6|

|N+8| = |N| - |N-8|

|N+6| + |N+8| - |N+68| + |N-68| = |N|

|LUCKY| = |N+6| + |N+8| - |N+68| *2 = 2 * ( 9<sup>n</sup> - 8<sup>n</sup> )

Now, we need to know the lucky number in a range that is not a power of 10, then we have to split our input in several blocks, each block with the form J * 10^K - (J+1) * 10^K - 1.

The number of such blocks is linear in the input size, that is no more than 10 * [digits of [number + 1]], so the total cost of the algorithm is also linear in the input size, that is log(n) where n is the greatest number in input.

When calculating each block we must take into account J, the prefix:

- if J contains both 6 and 8 we can skip the block since the number is
  not lucky
- if J contains either 6 or 8 but not both, then the formula for this block is |N-8| or |N-6| = 9^K
- in the remaining case the formula is 9^K - 8^K.

So, in total:

- add 1 to your input numbers since the algorithm exclude the upper bound of the range
- slice your number in blocks
- calculate the lucky numbers and for each input number, then subtract them to find the result

To do a quick check consider the case where you have the range 1 to 1000000000000000000 (18 digits), since 1 and 1000000000000000000 are not lucky you can directly apply the formula 2 * ( 9<sup>18</sup> - 8 <sup>18</sup> ).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long countLucky(long number) {
    //Algorithm excludes upper bound, so increase it by to include
    number++;

    long ncopy=number;
    //Count digits
    int size=0;
    while (ncopy>0) {
        ncopy/=10;
        size++;
    }

    ncopy=number;

    //Extract digits into array
    int digits[size];
    for (int d=0;ncopy>0;d++) {
        digits[d]=ncopy%10;
        ncopy/=10;
    }

    //Calculate powers of 10, 9, 8 starting with size-1
    long pow10=1;
    long pow9=1;
    long pow8=1;
    for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
        pow10*=10;
        pow9*=9;
        pow8*=8;
    }

    bool prefix6=false;
    bool prefix8=false;

    long count=0;

    for (int d=size-1;d>=0;d--) {
        //Both digits present in prefix, so no more lucky numbers can be found
        if (prefix6 && prefix8) {
            break;
        }
        for (int block=0;block<digits[d];block++) {
            if ((prefix6 || (block==6)) && (prefix8 || (block==8))) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((prefix6 || (block==6)) || (prefix8 || (block==8))) {
                count+=pow9;
            } else {
                count+=2*(pow9-pow8);
            }
        }

        //Calculate new powers
        pow10/=10;
        pow9/=9;
        pow8/=8;

        //Update prefix status
        prefix6 = prefix6 || (digits[d]==6);
        prefix8 = prefix8 || (digits[d]==8);
    }

    cout << endl;

    return count;
}

int main() {
    long c=countLucky(3363728910382456)-countLucky(92871036442);
    cout << "Result    " << c << endl;
    cout << "Solution  " << 1160053175781729 << endl;
}
```

Comment: This only gives you a count if the upper bound of the range is of the form 10^n-1.  How do you count how many lucky numbers there are less than some arbitrary upper bound like 686?

Comment: @Wyck I added the remaining, part, not the code yet, but the algorithm is now complete

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is not to test each numbers in that range, but instead you should be finding the answer through number theory.

A way to find the answer, is to first find all the numbers in a range that has the number `6`, then find all the numbers in that same range that has the number `8` in it. Then you minus the numbers that have both of them.

Below I have a piece of code that just count the lucky number from any 10^n (which includes 10^0, or 1) to any 10^m:

```
unsigned long long luckyCount(unsigned long long N)
{
    for(auto tempN = N; tempN != 1; tempN /= 10) if(tempN % 10) throw;
    // Just some error check, so you can't input any number other than 10^n

    unsigned long long T = 0, D = 0, C = 0;
    while(N /= 10)
    {
        D = D * 8 + T * 2;
        T = T * 9 + std::pow(10, C);
        ++C;
    }
    return T * 2 - D * 2;
}

unsigned long long luckyCount(unsigned long long L, unsigned long long R)
{
    return luckyCount(R) - luckyCount(L);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long L, R;
    cin >> L >> R;
    std::cout << luckyCount(L, R) << "\n";
}
```

For each iteration, the amount of number that have a `6` in it and a `8` in it are the same, and both of them are denoted as `T`. And the amount of numbers that have both `6` and `8` in it are denoted as `D`.

Hopefully this will give you a starting point, and you algorithm will be running at O(log(N)).

Answer (score -1):

I won't give you a complete algorithm, but just a starting point.

How many lucky numbers are there between 1 and 100?

All the ones in the form 6x + the ones like x6 + 1 (66) + all the 8x + all the x8 + 1 (88), where x can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9. So there are

(8 + 8 + 1) * 2 = 34 lucky numbers <sup>(*)</sup>.

How many lucky numbers are between a and b?

The ones between 1 and b minus the ones between a and 1.

keep up the reasoning and you'll end up with an algorithm with a complexity better than O(n).

<sup>(*) Which are: 6, 8, 16, 18, 26, 28, 36, 38, 46, 48, 56, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69, 76, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 87, 88, 89, 96, 98.</sup>